# Java simple commission program, return data based on search (JOptionPane)

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm creating a simple commission program with the data of the sales people already in the code. I just want to find a way to search for a NAME and return their name total salary. I've hit a roadblock for the past few hours trying to do this.

```
public class SalesPeople {

String personName;
double annualSalary;
double salesAmount;
double percentComission;

public SalesPeople(String xPersonName, double xAnnualSalary, double xSalesAmount, double xPercentComission) {
    personName = xPersonName;
    annualSalary = xAnnualSalary;
    salesAmount = xSalesAmount;
    percentComission = xPercentComission;
}

double totalSalary = annualSalary + (salesAmount * percentComission);

public String getPersonName() {
    return personName;
}
public double getAnnualSalary() {
    return annualSalary;
}
public double getSalesAmount() {
    return salesAmount;
}
public double getPercentComission() {
    return percentComission;
}
public double getTotalSalary() {
    return totalSalary;
}
}
```

In the last few lines of the class below are where I'm having trouble.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CommissionCalc {
    public static void main (String [] args ) {

        ArrayList<SalesPeople> salesList = new ArrayList<SalesPeople>();


        // PersonName, AnnualSalary, SalesAmount, PercentComission

        SalesPeople salesPerson1 = new SalesPeople ("Bob", 30000, 5000, .09);
        SalesPeople salesPerson2 = new SalesPeople ("Jane", 40000, 7000, .10);

        salesList.add(salesPerson1);
        salesList.add(salesPerson2);


        String userInput;

        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of a sales person:");


        if((salesList.get(0).getPersonName()).equals(userInput)) {

        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < salesList.size(); cnt++)  {
            if((salesList.get(cnt).getPersonName()).equals(userInput)) {
                System.out.println(salesList.get(cnt).getPersonName() + salesList.get(cnt).getTotalSalary());
            }
        }
            }
        }


}           
}
}
```

The name prints, but I'm getting a return of 0.0 on total salary. I just can't get it to return the Name and TotalSalary. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `System.out.println(salesList.get(cnt).getPersonName());` instead of `System.out.println(salesList.get(cnt));`. For name and total salary use code like this:

```
System.out.println("Person name: " + salesList.get(cnt).getPersonName() + ", Total salary: " + salesList.get(cnt).getPersonName().getTotalSalary());
```

For total salary, replace your `getTotalSalary()` method with this code:

```
public double getTotalSalary() {
    return getAnnualSalary() + (getSalesAmount() * getPercentComission());
}
```

Comment: That only works if I search for Bob. Nothing happens when I search for the second sales person.

Comment: @user3741689 You need to delete `if((salesList.get(0).getPersonName()).equals(userInput))` it's check only first element of `ArrayList` and not goin to second.

Comment: @user3741689 You see total salary of Bob?

Comment: Getting there. I deleted that line but getting a red underline on the last   .getTotalSalary() in the println

Comment: Still getting 0.0's on the total salary.

Comment: @user3741689 Are you delete `{ }` of if statement code?

Comment: Nice! Thanks a ton. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set totalSalary in SalesPeople constructor. So the code would be:

```
public class SalesPeople {

   String personName;
   double annualSalary;
   double salesAmount;
   double percentComission;
   double totalSalary;

   public SalesPeople(String xPersonName, double xAnnualSalary, double xSalesAmount, double xPercentComission) {
       personName = xPersonName;
       annualSalary = xAnnualSalary;
       salesAmount = xSalesAmount;
       percentComission = xPercentComission;
       totalSalary = annualSalary + (salesAmount * percentComission);
   }   
...
}
```

Before SalesPeople class initialization, the default value for annualSalary,  salesAmount and percentComission are 0 (or null as undefined).If you define totalSalary outside constructor, totalSalary will always be 0. 
The alternative solution would be: define a setTotalSalary() method in your SalesPeople class, and call it after you create a SalsePeople instance.

```
public void setTotalSalary(){
      totalSalary = this.annualSalary + (this.salesAmount * this,percentComission);
}
```

And call setTotalSalary() you define a SalesPeople instance.

```
SalesPeople salesPerson1 = new SalesPeople ("Bob", 30000, 5000, .09);
salesPerson1.setTotalSalary();
```